# TypeScript with PHP in Visual Studio 2013 Community

Tags: php, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have an important question:
Can I use TypeScript in Visual Studio 2013 Community with PHP Tools for Visual Studio 2013 or any other PHP tool? I want to start a new PHP project and I just wondered if there's any possibly way to use TypeScript with PHP together. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out! There's an option to add a new "Text file" and after that I gave .ts extension to that new file it works! There's a shiny new TypeScript file and works fine!

Comment: have you tried this in 2015. If I rename a js file to ts, visual studio doesn't seem to notice.